# rvm/ruby - bundler not working when trying to create gem skeleton

Tags: ubuntu, rubygems, rvm, bundler

I updated my ubuntu version from 12.04 to 13.04 and so had to reinstall everything... Most things are now working... However, 'bundler' is not.

i.e. when running the following to create a new gem skeleton:

```
bundle gem np_search
```

it gives me the following error:

when under rvm ruby v. 2.0.0 (same error seen with 1.9.3)

```
Unfortunately, a fatal error has occurred. Please see the Bundler troubleshooting documentation at http://bit.ly/bundler-issues. Thanks!
/home/ismail/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:689:in ``': No such file or directory - git (Errno::ENOENT)
from /home/ismail/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:689:in `gem'
from /home/ismail/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
from /home/ismail/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
from /home/ismail/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:344:in `dispatch'
from /home/ismail/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:434:in `start'
from /home/ismail/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/ismail/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:3:in `with_friendly_errors'
from /home/ismail/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:20:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ismail/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
from /home/ismail/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

when running under the system ruby (i.e. without rvm) ruby version 2.0.0

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/bundle: /usr/bin/ruby1.8: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I have carried out all the steps in the link in the first error message but still the problem remained. Also, had a look on google and stackoverflow but couldn't find anything that fixed the problem...

This is what I get when typing  "bundle env"

when in rvm:

```
Bundler 1.3.5
Ruby 2.0.0 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 247) [x86_64-linux]
Rubygems 2.0.7
rvm 1.22.5 (stable)
GEM_HOME /home/ismail/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247
GEM_PATH /home/ismail/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247:/home/ismail/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global

Gemfile
<No Gemfile found>

Gemfile.lock
<No Gemfile.lock found>
```

when using system ruby 2.0.0, 'bundle env' just gives me

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/bundle: /usr/bin/ruby1.8: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I did try to export the ruby path to the .bashrc (something I read online) by typing this...

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/ruby /usr/local/bin/ruby
```

But it made no difference.

Many thanks for all your help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this happens because bundler requires `git` for this command to be installed - from the mentioned code line:

```
git_user_name = `git config user.name`.chomp
```

install `git` and then it should work just fine ... at least for this part.